# Camera jitter in unity when setting position in Update, and setting camera rotation in LateUpdate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I understand that this is a somewhat frequently asked question, however I have yet to find a solution for my specific scenario:

I am creating a server authoritative game, the server calculates movement and sends it to the client in the form of a Vector3. This Vector3 is stored in a variable when received, and in update, the position is set equal to the Vector3.

Camera rotation is client-authoritative, rotation is calculated based on the mouse delta, and is added to the current rotation. The Y axis rotation is applied to the entire body (to turn), and the X axis rotation is applied to the camera (to look up and down). This is all done in late update

When moving and looking at an object, it appears to jitter very fast. All of the solutions I have found do not work, I assume this is because they are designed to fix camera jitter with rigidbody movement

Comment: Could you post your code and maybe add a video of exactly what jitter you are talking? I think the issue might simply be how you get the values from the server / network lag .. you should probably add some kind of interpolation (`Vector3.Lerp`, `Vector3.MoveTowards` etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When messing with physics, rotations, positions and other related stuff, its more recommended using `FixedUpdate` instead of `Update`.

**Why is this?**

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html

Well, `Fixed Update` it is called fixed frame-rate frame and is more reliable for physics.

Comment: But when I use FixedUpdate for the camera, it appears as if it has a lower frame rate when rotating

Comment: Try using FixedUpdate for the position of your player, and use Update for the Camera. Also try and setting the position of the camera outside the sever

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has this issue, i fixed it by rotating the character using `rb.MoveRotation` instead of `transform.rotation`, while setting its interpolation mode to `interpolate`